# How to format date with default zone without the numeric offset

Tags: date, datetime, go, datetime-format

If I scan date from database to a struct that contains date in time.Time, by default it will print like this:

```
"2019-11-27T16:38:55+07:00"
```

Is there a way to format it like this, without re-parsing everything that has time.Time type?

```
"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
```

I can reformat everything manually, but there has to be a better way. Because I'm scanning into a slice, to reformat the date, I had to loop the result just to do that.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by that format? Do you just want to convert to UTC time and put the `"Z"` instead of having a numeric offset?

Comment: Yes, but I want to avoid re-formatting it if possible, because by default it has numeric offset instead of Z.

Comment: I think you'll have to reformat (if I understand you right on that) since the way a time is printed is just a formatting thing in the first place since different looking times may actually refer to the same instant. For example `"2020-01-05T23:34:17-08:00"` and `2020-01-06T07:34:17Z` are the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [.UTC()](https://godoc.org/time) method of `time.Time` to get the time value in UTC timezone, and then re-format it again into string, then you will get the equivalent date in UTC.

```
str1 := "2019-11-27T16:38:55+07:00"
tme1, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, str1)

tme2 := tme1.UTC()
str2 := tme2.Format(time.RFC3339)

fmt.Println("str1", str1) // str1 2019-11-27T16:38:55+07:00
fmt.Println("str2", str2) // str2 2019-11-27T09:38:55Z
```

Working playground https://play.golang.org/p/7uRKDeRZBUx

---

> This is for an API that will be used by a front end app, that requires it to be formatted like this.

Whether it is in javascript, go, or any other programming/scripting language, parsing equivalent string of dates in different timezone will result an equivalent date. Take a look at example below in js:

```
console.log(new Date("2019-11-27T16:38:55+07:00").toString())
// "Wed Nov 27 2019 16:38:55 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time)"

console.log(new Date("2019-11-27T09:38:55Z").toString())
// "Wed Nov 27 2019 16:38:55 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time)"
```

See both date parsing operations generate the same string after being parsed and converted into string

Comment: Well technically this is what I want to avoid. I'm scanning a slice of struct from database, and this way I had to loop just to reformat the date. I guess there is no other way.

Comment: I'm curious why you need it to be in UTC timezone, since both are equivalent. you wont get any different result when doing selection condition operation or when formatting it to string on the datetimeobject

Comment: This is for an API that will be used by a front end app, that requires it to be formatted like this.

Comment: even in the front end, if the js is performing the parsing properly, either it is in UTC or in other timezone format - both date will still be equivalent

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid I'm not sure whether you understood or not about how timezone work. but please take a look at my updated answer :)